# Routing in ASP.net Web forms with id parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, routes

I registered this MapPageRoute in my RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "ProfileRoute",
            "Profile/{userid}",
            "~/Profile.aspx"
            );
```

and this is how I redirect to the Profile page with the id Parameter (from SignIn to Profile)

```
Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("ProfileRoute", new { userid = usersign.Text }));
```

However, it displays the error "Server Error in '/' Application." and "The resource cannot be found"
The requested URL would look like that "Requested URL: /Profile/id"

I used the following Route method previously

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Profile.aspx?id={0}", id));
```

But i want to change this to a better and more stable routing method which is somehow similar to MVC routing.

What errors can I fix in my code? And how can I accomplish my goal in Web forms?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
I removed the following code from my RouteConfig.cs

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and it worked

I don't need this code (for now) since I haven't created any controllers. Unless I need them, then I guess this code is not much necessary for my project.